# how to checked input checkbox datatable laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

i want to make a statement if is_participant is one then check the box, but i tried but it doesn't work

```
$user = User::with('regency.province');
        return DataTables::of($user)
            ->editColumn('is_participant', function ($user) {
                return '<input ' . $user->is_participant == 1 ? "checked" : "" . ' type="checkbox" id="' . $user->id . '">';
            })
```

is there something missing in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the below code. I have tried to change quote formatting just the way PHP accepts.

```
->editColumn("is_participant", function ($user) {
         $checked = ($user-> is_participant == 1) ? 'checked' : '';
         return ' <input type="checkbox" id="' . $user->id . '" ' . $checked . '> ';
  });
```